# Send a String parameter from VFP 9 to a dll created on c++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll, visual-foxpro

I've created a DLL in C++ Visual Studio using OpenCV to capture the image of camera. I receive parameters String.

When sending usually what i get is a "Declare DLL call caused an exception", and I'm not sure if the problem is the type of variable I'm sending on VFP or the type I'm receiving on C++.

**DLL**

```
extern "C" 
    {     
        __declspec(dllexport) void CamPhoto(int,String);
    }


extern void __cdecl CamPhoto(int cam, string name)  
{  

    char aux[100];
    strcpy(aux, name.c_str());

    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    capture= cvCreateCameraCapture(cam);
    IplImage *frame=0;

    //SaveImage
    char FileName[100];
    char auxpath[100];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        sprintf(FileName,"/%s.jpg",aux);
        strcpy(auxpath,"C:/Users/Emi/Pictures");
        strcat(auxpath,FileName);

        cvSaveImage(auxpath,frame);
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    delete [] aux;

}
```

**VFP**

```
DECLARE CamPhotoIn "CamCapture.dll" INTEGER, STRING
CamPhoto(0, "TestVFP")
```

Comment: What is VFP? Just what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to...  This way you are trying to force passing the pointer to the string instead of the string itself.  It might get through for you.

```
DECLARE CamPhotoIn "CamCapture.dll" INTEGER, @STRING

testString = "TestVFP"
CamPhoto(0, @testString )
```